# how to convert a HTML web page into a PDF file using Java

Tags: java, pdf

i've been searching on the internet on how to convert a HTML page into a PDF file using Java. i found a lot of pointers, and in short, they don't work or are too difficult to implement. i also downloaded a commercial product, pdf4ml; the API is something i'd be happy to work with, except that when i crawled a simple page on wikipedia, i get a out of memory error (setting Xmx to 1024 M). in some approaches, they suggest converting HTML -> XHTML -> FO -> PDF. however, i am getting a lot of exceptions for the XHTML-to-FO XLS file; and reading the documentations, it's not something that i have enough time to understand right now.

here are my questions/concerns.
1. is there another cohesive API out there that will easily convert HTML to PDF (commercial or not)?
2. is there a way i can simply capture a HTML page and store it as a single file. this approach would be similar to using internet explorer's way of saving a web page as a web archive (single file, MHT format)?

any help is appreciated. (btw, i know this question has been asked repeatedly, but in addition to the original spirit of the question, i'm opened to other ways). thanks.

Comment: Aside from automation, you can use BullZip PDF Printer to print the HTML page to PDF.

Comment: this is around the one hundredth time the "html->pdf in java" question has been asked.  Part of the reason Stack Overflow exists is so you can check the answers to previously asked questions.  Do So.

Answer (score 6):

Try [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/), which is using WebKit. Another option (I'm using that currently) is using OpenOffice (remote controlled via macros).

Comment: This option is amazing! Webkit does a great job at HTML5+CSS3 rendering.

Answer (score 1):

you may use [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/) open source Java lib for that, and read [this](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html)

or use [YaHPConverter](http://www.allcolor.org/YaHPConverter/) open source Java lib.

or do this whith help of [icepdf](http://www.icesoft.com/products/icepdf.html) popular open source lib

or use [pd4ml](http://pd4ml.com/), but it not free, only trial.

or use [this](http://www.easysw.com/htmldoc/), and [this](http://www.easysw.com/htmldoc/htmldoc.html#6_6) is man for it.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents using opensource tools:

You can use either [Capture screenshots with Selenium](http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2009/10/selenium-tip-of-the-week-screenshot/) or [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/?redir=1) to save html page's screenshot in an image file from your Java code. And once you have image file you can [convert it to pdf again from your Java code](http://image2pdf.sourceforge.net/).

**EDIT:** 
It seems you can do all that in 1 step using [itext Html to Pdf](http://javaxtendsolutions.wordpress.com/2011/01/03/itext-1-5-html-to-pdf/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you could Try

1) cobra html rendering engine http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp

2) htmleditorkit -- part of jdk

3) JWebPane

Use the rendering kit to parse and render html. The rendered out put is a swing component. Swing component can be used by itext to generate pdf file out put

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [Pdfcrowd](http://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/). It is an easy to use commercial online API with many options and with support for Java.

It can create PDF either from web pages or raw HTML code.

Comment: Unfortunately, Pdfcrowd isn't free.